# check whether json data array is empty or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This is my ajax code, I need to check whether json data has an array or not?
How can I?
I have tried this but yet it shows me wrong output.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'data': data},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          if(data)
          {
            console.log('data is there');
          }
          else
          {
            console.log('data is not there'); 
          }
```

This is response I am giving in return to ajax.

```
<?php
$json_data_array = '[]';
return $json_data_array;
?>
```

How can I check?

Comment: JSON.parse(data).length

Answer (score 2):

You need to check it's length. Array in condition `if(array)` is true when it has no items.

```js
if([]) {
    console.log('True');
}
```

Check the `length` property

```js
if([].length) {
   console.log('True');
}
```

Comment: Thanks which will be good options length or normal [] this for checking?

Comment: Depends on your logic. If empty array is ok (considering to be true) for you, use the first, if not - the second

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can check the length

```
  var size= myarray.length;
    if(size>=1) 
    {
       alert("not empty");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("empty");
    }
```

In php you can check with the following method

```
if(!empty($myarray))
{
    echo "Not Empty";
}
else
{
    echo "Empty";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to json encode your return value from php like this

```
<?php
$json_data_array = '[]';
return json_encode($json_data_array);
?>
```

Then you have to check the length of returned array at javascript side like this

```
if(data.length > 0){
  console.log('data is there');
}else{
  console.log('data is not there'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using below method:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( your_variable ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array' );
}else{
    alert('Not Array');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use and  echo json_encode($json_data_array);

build a normal array and then convert it to json it will be easier

```
<?php
$json_data_array = array();
echo json_encode($json_data_array);
?>
```

in your jquery use

```
if($.isEmptyObject(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript empty array ([]) return true. You should check array.length